# Why do I get extra commas in my python slqlite SELECT results?

Tags: python, select, sqlite

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.  Can someone please help?
When I run the following statement:

```
cur.execute("SELECT created FROM datafiles where path = '%s'" % self.srchfilepath.displayText()
list = cur.fetchall()
```

(self.srchfilepath.displayText() is just a field on a GUI)

The results I get is:

```
[('testing',), ('testing',)]
```

The actual data is correct, it is just in a format I don't understand.

I can't figure out where the extra commas within the parens are coming from.  I am trying to put this data in back into a listbox field for display and selection, but I need a list that the field will accept.  Clearly this is not what it wants.  Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong and how I can make the result into something the `Listbox` will accept?

Answer (score 15):

You retrieved a list of *rows*, and each row is a tuple of columns. As each row contains only *one* column the rows are tuples with *one* value each.

In python, it is the *comma* that makes an expression a tuple, even if there is only one element:

```
>>> 1,
(1,)
```

Simply select the first element of each row:

```
result_list = [row[0] for row in cur.fetchall()]
```